# Pipenv shell fails to create virtual environment in Python 3.8

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I'm new to Django, and I'm starting a tutorial for Django with React, and I'm struggling with creating the virtual environment by using

```
pipenv shell
```

as per the tutorial's instructions. I have seen similar questions, but they have been either with another python version or the error is just different, and the answers haven't helped me. The error says the following:

```
Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 385, in shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       do_shell(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2155, in do_shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       ensure_project(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 570, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       ensure_virtualenv(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 505, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       do_create_virtualenv(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Iván\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 934, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       raise exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException(
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: Traceb
```

I reinstalled pip (19.3.1) and pipenv to be sure, with no change, and my environment variables are correct, I think, they are as follows:
[Variable (PYTHONPATH)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pQmc.png)

Comment: Windows supports max 255 chars in directory path try to create your env in C:/

Comment: Is it the full error message? It looks like the end has been cut.

Answer (score 1):

try:
python -m virtualenv venv